# Property with JsonIgnore attribute not ignored when deserializing with MissingMemberHandling.Error

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm currently using Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2 but I've also validated that this behavior is consistent starting 8.0.1~current. To my understanding, JsonIgnore Attribute is used as a hint to NOT serialize/deserialize. However, when combined with MissingMemberHandling.Error in JsonSerializationSettings, it is showing odd behavior when deserializing. I want to know if this a bug in Newtonsoft.Json or if there is an explanation for this strange behavior.

Here's a sample class:

```
public class Sample
{
  public string Id {get; set;}

  [JsonIgnore]
  public string SubscriptionId { get; set;}
}
```

And a sample string to deserialize:

```
{
  "id":"testId",
  "subscriptionId":"testSubscriptionId"
}
```

[CASE1] Using the default constructor, deserializing does not throw any errors. It only sets the id and keeps subscriptionId null.

[CASE2] When I add a JsonConstructor only with the id, it will throw. Could not find member 'subscriptionId' on object of type 'Sample'.

```
[JsonConstructor]
public Sample(string id)
{
  this.Id = id;
}
```

[CASE3] When I add a JsonConstructor with id and subscriptionId, it does not throw.

```
[JsonConstructor]
public Sample(string id, string subscriptionId)
{
  this.Id = id;
}
```

I've looked through Newtonsoft.Json code here ln2196 (https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs),

```
CreatorPropertyContext creatorPropertyContext = new CreatorPropertyContext(memberName)
{
    ConstructorProperty = contract.CreatorParameters.GetClosestMatchProperty(memberName),
    Property = contract.Properties.GetClosestMatchProperty(memberName)
};
propertyValues.Add(creatorPropertyContext);

JsonProperty? property = creatorPropertyContext.ConstructorProperty ?? creatorPropertyContext.Property;
if (property != null && !property.Ignored)
{
    // logic for populating the value
}
else
{
    // if missing member handling is true, throw
}
```

[CASE3] makes sense to me because the constructor is explicitly anticipating the subscriptionId, so it can override the JsonIgnore (and is considered not ignored). [CASE2] makes sense to me too, because JsonIgnore attribute is set, it should not be considered when deserializing. However, why does [CASE1] not consider this property ignored?

==========

Edit: 
Looking more through how json properties get initialized in the default constructor case, it seems that it is intentional that json ignore fields should not be considered as a missing field. When using the default constructor, JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject goes through the second path of Ignored, not the first path where it doesn't find the property.

```
JsonProperty? property = contract.Properties.GetClosestMatchProperty(propertyName);
if (property == null)
{
    // if property is not found and MissingMemberHandling.Error is set, throw
}
if (property.Ignored || !ShouldDeserialize(reader, property, newObject))
{
    // if marked ignored, don't throw, and also don't set.
}
```

So now I believe I've hit an obscure bug in Newtonsoft.Json and that [CASE2] should actually align with [CASE1] and not throw. 
Here's a pull request to fix it: 
https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/2224

Comment: Can you please clarify what you expect different in your case1: "Using the default constructor, deserializing does not throw any errors. It only sets the id and keeps subscriptionId null"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I would expect it to behave like case2. Since it is marked ignored, I feel it should also throw. It should behave as if that property does not exist, just like case2.