# MissingMemberHandling.Error doesn't throw when property is set with jsonignore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, json.net

After setting MissingMemberHandling.Error does not seem to throw serialization exception for a property set with jsonignore
how to handle this?

```
public class Account
{
public string FullName { get; set; }
public bool Deleted { get; set; }
[JsonIgnore]
public bool DeletedDate { get; set; }
}

string json = @"{
'FullName': 'Dan Deleted',
'Deleted': true,
'DeletedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00'
}";

try
{
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error
});
}
catch (JsonSerializationException ex) //No Error returned
{

Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

expected a JsonSerializationException error but obj has deleteddate set to null

Comment: Seems like this may be a known issue, see [Property with JsonIgnore attribute not ignored when deserializing with MissingMemberHandling.Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59062524/3744182).  What is your question?  Are you looking for a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't use the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to catch `MissingMemberHandling` error messages, here's why. There's a solution at the bottom, and I've provided the code and test results, check it out.

**Reason**

The `MissingMemberHandling` setting is used for cases where a member like 'DeletedDate' cannot be found on the object.

**Here is the sample in official site.**

[image]

#### Solution

**1. We need to create a custom `AccountConverter`.**

**AccountConverter.cs**

```
using JsonIgnoreDemo.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonIgnoreDemo
{
    public class AccountConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(Account);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
            var properties = jo.Properties().Select(p => p.Name);
            if (properties.Contains("DeletedDate"))
            {
                throw new JsonSerializationException("DeletedDate should not be included in JSON.");
            }

            Account account = new Account();
            serializer.Populate(jo.CreateReader(), account);
            return account;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Use it in you method.**

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
    string json = @"{
                   'FullName': 'Dan Deleted',
                   'Deleted': true,
                   'DeletedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00'
                   }";

    try
    {
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new AccountConverter() }
        });
    }
    catch (JsonSerializationException ex) //No Error returned
    {

        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

**3. Test Result**

[image]

Press Continue.

[image]